# redirection after some action with commandButton

Tags: html, jsf, navigation

I have a command button:

```
<h:commandButton value="button" action="#{bean.button}" />
```

I need to perform a redirection after the action ends.

What I do is to return a string with the page name.

The outcome is the desired page but the URL is of the previous page.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to update browser's url, you need to [tell jsf to perform a redirect](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-page-forward-vs-page-redirect/). Basically you need to append `?faces-redirect=true` to your outcome value.

Comment: if that bean is @RequestScoped would this redirecion will erase its content? if so, how could I perform a redirect + execute some action with a button. thanks a lot

Comment: If the bean is `@RequestScoped` the content is erased. If you want to perform some action, it's enough to put it into the action backing method logic, isn't it?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15074911/jsf-execute-action-on-some-input-and-then-href and if you can answer there it would be great